# iOS WebRTC Local Media NSInvalidArgumentException [RTCI420Frame nativeHandle]

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, apprtc

I am trying to create a local media stream in my iOS webRTC app. See code below

```
let localStream = pcFactory.mediaStream(withLabel: "ARDAMS")!

let audio = pcFactory.audioTrack(withID: "ARDAMSa0")
localStream.addAudioTrack(audio!)

var device: AVCaptureDevice?
for captureDevice in AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo){
    if let captureDevice = captureDevice as? AVCaptureDevice{
        if captureDevice.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front{
            device = captureDevice
        }
    }
}

if let device = device{
    let capture = RTCVideoCapturer(deviceName: device.localizedName)
    let videoSource = pcFactory.videoSource(with: capture, constraints: nil)
    localVideoTrack = pcFactory.videoTrack(withID: "ARDAMSv0", source: videoSource)
    localStream.addVideoTrack(localVideoTrack)
}


self.peerConnection?.add(localStream)

localVideoTrack?.add(localVideoView)
```

Everything works, but when after I add the `localVideoView` to the `localVideoTrack` I get an error:

```
-[RTCI420Frame nativeHandle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170010620

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RTCI420Frame nativeHandle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170010620'
```

All of the code is running on the main thread and the app has the appropriate permissions and plist keys. When I walk through the code line by line using the debugger everything seems to be running correctly. This code was taken from the Obj-C AppRTC demo, it has just been converted to swift. I can't seem to find the difference between my swift project that crashes and the working AppRTC project. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am testing on a 64 bit device. Thanks!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, have you solved this issue?

Comment: @Nilesh I am not sure what the solution was, but I removed all of the unused RTC frameworks and files, cleared derived data and rebuild.

Comment: Okay, I will also try and let you know.

Comment: Can u please tell me or share a screenshot which RTC files you have removed?

Comment: Is there any way to store the audio conversation of WebRTC session to iOS device locally(documents directory or somewhere locally to play later) ? @AlexPelletier